# practice in using retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm new in using retrofit...
I can get `id`, `title` and `thumbnail` but I can't get object on arraylist `tags`..?

Please tell me how can i do...

Here is my json:

```
{
  code: 200,
  result: {
  id: "7064",
  title: "my title",
  thumbnail: "http://myimage.com/image.jpg",
  tags: [
  {
    name: "php",
    slug: "php"
  },
  {
   name: "dependencies manager",
   slug: "dependencies-manager"
  },
  {
   name: "dependencies",
   slug: "dependencies"
  },
  {
   name: "packagist",
   slug: "packagist"
  }
  ]
 }
}
```

and this my model using gson serialized

```
public class Detail extends Observable implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("code")
    public Integer code;
    @SerializedName("result")
    public Result result;

    public class Result implements Serializable {
        @SerializedName("id")
        public String id;
        @SerializedName("title")
        public String title;
        @SerializedName("date")
        public String date;
        @SerializedName("thumbnail")
        public String thumbnail;
        @SerializedName("tags")
        public ArrayList<Tags> tags = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public class Tags implements Serializable {
        @SerializedName("name")
        public String name;
        @SerializedName("slug")
        public String slug;
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

and my API

```
@GET("api/posts/detail/{id}")
    Call<Detail> getDetails (@Path("id") String id);
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong what's the error you are getting ?

Comment: btw be aware of an error in your json 
` title: "my title",`

Comment: I'm not getting error but while write code on android studio arraylist "tags" can't apparent on suggestion..

Comment: i correct -> title:"my title"...
I'm not getting error but while write code on android studio arraylist "tags" can't apparent on suggestion...

Boukharist have you project using restrofit 2.0 with handling json structure same mine

Comment: @AhmadEfendi Why are you extending Observable for your Details class?

Answer (score 0):

Instead `ArrayList` use `List` and do not initialize it. So this going to be like this

```
@SerializedName("tags")
List<Tags> tags;
```